# Access page in VM image and not VM Role?

Tags: azure, azure-vm-role

I have my VM image with Sharepoint 2010 deployed to Azure , have create VM role hosted service to access it. What URL should I give to access page in my VM Image and not VM Role.by default it gives a URL for VM role that just opens the IIS page but my actual application is installed in VM Image.

Answer (score 1):

I'll give you the same response I posted on [your messages in the MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazuretroubleshooting/thread/9ff10956-f42b-4f42-a2a0-269835a462ed) forum....

Sharepoint hosting in Windows Azure is NOT supported nor recommended at this time. The stateless nature of the Windows Azure virtual machines makes is exceedingly difficult to reliable operation SharePoint in that envionment.

I highly recommend you abandon the current line of thinking and re-evaluate the scenario. Otherwise you are likely setting yourself up for a long and painful road that ultimate will be less than optimal.

Comment: Yes thats right , am not looking at Sharepoint to Maintain state,am using some of the features in My complex app.Moreover SP has been installed on my base image,so even if it reboots I dont have an issue. Lets say I want to display my default page in VM Image - IIS and not VM role IIS how can I achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how to differentiate "VM Image - IIS" and "VM Role IIS". If i understand correctly your objective is show the default page which is part of web server running in your VM (because it is VM role and you have uploaded your own VM. In this scenario in the VM, there is only one IIS server which you have configured to run SP on it. So VM Role IIS and VM Image IIS are same, in my understanding. What you really need is to have an HTTP endpoint (HTTPS as well if you want to) added in your VM Role application so your host machine can be configured to have your default ASPX or SP based ASPX page accessible when VM is running. Be sure to test that your IIS server is fully functional, the way you want to see on Azure, on your VM before you upload it.

Finally @Brent suggestion are to the point so please follow his valuable advice and become pain free.